# How to get the directory without sub directory in c#

Tags: c#, directory

I would like to ask is there any way to get all the folder/directory name in a path:

My problem is:

I would like to get several folders in Local Disk C: but I don't want to use the following code to search all the folder in C: which causes the program stuck.

```
        foreach (string dirPath in Directory.GetDirectories(source, "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories))
        {
            ...
        }
```

Comment: See the other option of the `SearchOption` enum.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
using System.IO;

var directories = Directory.GetDirectories("c:\\");
```

This should give you all the directories at the root level of the C drive.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
string[] dirs = Directory.GetDirectories(@"c:\", "*", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly);
```

This should give you just top directory only.